# CODE IS NOT RUNNING - VS 2013 (not telerik issue)

Tags: visual-studio

I am using VS 2013 Ultimate and MVC5. When i run the debugger I get this message:

```
/***********************************************/
   Code is not running
   The current thread is not currently running code or the call stack could not be obtained.
/**************************************************/
```

The problem happens also when i run other type of projects that do not use IIS (such as VSTO). So the IISExpress fix will not work here.

I looked around and found a few similar problems that pointed at removing JustMock extension by telerik. However, i do not have this extension installed.

Comment: I literally looked all over the web and couldn't find a solution to this problem. I was suggested to reinstall VS - it didn't help. I suspect that the reason for this bug is one of the extensions i added to VS. However, it appears that removing those extension became challenging by itself. I eventually decided to install a virtual machine and install e fresh copy of VS on it. I don't have the problem anymore. It's not exactly a solution but a nice workaround.

Comment: I had the same problem, but I don't think it was related to any extensions. It went away after restarting Windows...

Answer (score 1):

It was enough for me to just restart Visual Studio 2013 to get debugging working again.

Comment: Oddly, same here. I tried to debug, cleans/rebuilds etc and found no cause. It was happening at such as a strange time, and after no major code changes... How odd

Answer (score 0):

This solution is a little tangential. But:

I started getting this bug on VS2012. Per recommendations elsewhere on the net, I removed all recent Windows Updates. No help.

I was aware that anti-virus programs on Windows probably monitor inter-process communication.

So then I told Kaspersky to explicitly exempt A) devenv.exe, and B) my app.exe.

No help.

So then I *disabled* the Kaspersky anti-virus I recently installed.

No help.

So then I *uninstalled* the Kaspersky anti-virus I recently installed.

And the error vanished. VS2012 is happy again. Me too.

Comment: When you uninstalled Kaspersky, did you also have to restart?

Answer (score 0):

After trying everything, I did the obvious... I removed the remote debugging tools from my client (debuggee) and downloaded the matching debugging tools (2013 update 5) in my case, and installed those on the target. And beautiful debugging returned, what a sight! a red dot with a yellow flash in it, and... variables and stack to look at... I am in tears.

Answer (score -1):

Try disable all vs extension.
I had this problem.And it turns out the PostSharp extension cause this problem.
I disable it and it works.